# Problems with mariadb and 'for' loops

Tags: sql, loops, for-loop, mariadb

Here's my MariaDB SQL. I want to do a for loop but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

```
    SET @varapartat=113;
    SET @vararea=4;
    FOR i IN (select element_id from element where element_apartat_fk=(@varapartat)) DO
      IF (select COUNT(*) from element_area where element_area_element_fk=(i.element_id) AND element_area_area_fk=(@varapartat))=0
      THEN
        INSERT INTO element_area (element_area_element_fk, element_area_area_fk)VALUES ((i.element_id), (@vararea))
      END IF;
    END FOR;
```

Comment: Can you show the error that you are getting?

Comment: If you are doing a `for` loop in SQL or in an application language using a SQL statement you are usually doing something wrong as the server is much better and looping than you. In your case, with `element_area_element_fk` as a unique key, `INSERT IGNORE ... SELECT` would seem to be the correct syntax eliminate most of the loops and conditions.